# Extract Multiple Columns

Tags: vba, excel

Below is the code I have tried with but it only worked for Column A, I want to do the same job with other columns:

```
Sub ColumnAMaster()
Dim lastRow As Long, lastRowMaster As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Master As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set Master = Sheets.Add
  Master.Name = "Master"
  lastRowMaster = 1
  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Master" Then
      lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=Master.Range("A" & lastRowMaster)
      lastRowMaster = Master.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us what you've got so far with details on where you're stuck or what error you're getting.

Comment: I have three worksheets in workbook and all those three sheets have data with multiple fields (header) but below are the fields which are common and I want to extract all this fields and consolidate all of them into the master sheet.- Fields are=                                                                                                           empname empid flmname empemail qaname tktnum RedLight comm percentage time_stamp

Comment: What code have you written to do this? We'll help you fix what you've got, but usually people won't just write it for you. Post your code in your original question

Comment: Actually I am not that good with VBA.

Comment: How can I add the question ?

Comment: Just remember, you'll never get good without the try/fail/adjust process. We all go through it. Under your post, just below the tags, you should see a little link that says `edit`. click that & paste you code in, then save it.  Also, this may help: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried doing it but I can't paste the codes. DO I need to type in the codes ?

Comment: Make sure you're in the 'edit' box, where it's plain text, not down below where it shows you a preview of what it will look like when posted. No, you won't need to re-type it, just paste it will be fine.

Comment: I am sorry if  am sounding very stupid but I have just started learning excel.

Comment: I have edited the question, can you please check.

Comment: That's great. Can you please put your original question back in there so we can see what it was you were after. Add it to the top of the post, don't replace the code that's there.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub Master_data()
 'declarations
Dim ws1 as worksheet
Dim ws2 as worksheet 
Dim ws3 as worksheet
Dim ws4 as worksheet
Dim i as long
Dim lastrow_sh1 as long
Dim lastrow_sh4 as long
Dim wb as workbook
set wb= application.activeworkbook
set ws1=wb.sheets("sheet1")
set ws2=wb.sheets("sheet2")
set ws3=wb.sheets("sheet3")
set ws4=wb.sheets("sheet4")

lastrow_sh1= ws1.range("A1").end(xlup).row
ws4.cells(1,1)="name"



for i =2 to lastrow_sh1 
        if ws1.cells(i,1)=ws2.cells(i,1) & ws3.cell(i,1)then
        lastrow_sh4=ws4.range(A1).end(xlup).row

      ws4.cells(lastrow_sh4+1,1)=ws1.cells(i,1)
      ws4.cells(lastrow_sh4+1,2)=ws1.cells(i,2)
      ws4.cells(lastrow_sh4+1,3)=ws1.cells(i,3)
      ws4.cells(lastrow_sh4+1,4)=ws3.cells(i,4)

                 endif

next i

end sub
```